# What is needed for a Secure WebSocket connection on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, qt, ssl, websocket

I wrote a QT tool using WebSockets with SSL. When I roll it out to an other Windows 10 machine it doesn't connect but produces a QAbstractSocket::UnsupportedSocketOperationError  on Client side. On server side I don't get any notification that a new client has connected.

The tool "Dependencies" shows no difference in dll's, a test without SSL worked fine as well as connecting from same network with my developer machine.

As is works fine with my developer machine I assume something is wrong/missing on the other Windows 10 machine. I have installed OpenSSL 1.1.0f on it but I have no idea what else to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was an encryption problem from QT. I solveded it by downloading the dll's (libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll) together with precompiled(!) MySql driver for my QT version from https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases and stored it into the application root folder. Additional I copied into here the "tls"-folder from qt/6.3.0/plugins/.